# Hbase cluster Replication | Monitoring replication lag across clusters

Tags: hbase, replication, lag

After setting up [cluster replication](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_cluster_replication) in Hbase, we want to monitor replication lag between clusters.

```
hbase(main):015:0> status 'replication'
version 1.2.6
1 live servers
<hostname>:
   SOURCE: PeerID=sep᐀node, AgeOfLastShippedOp=0, SizeOfLogQueue=0, TimeStampsOfLastShippedOp=Fri Aug 02 18:24:18 IST 2019, Replication Lag=346
   SINK  : AgeOfLastAppliedOp=0, TimeStampsOfLastAppliedOp=Tue Jul 30 17:45:24 IST 2019
```

Can anyone help what that "Replication Lag" in the output means actually? How is calculated in terms of available [replication metrics](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_replication_metrics) ?
Incase we want to monitor replication lag in terms for time lag, just like in any traditional master slave replication, how does one achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

"Replication lag" is relatively straightforward, compared to some other HBase terms -- it shows how far behind replication process is with respect to the edits yet to be replicated.

From [source code](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/replication/regionserver/MetricsSource.java#L306): *TimeStampNextToReplicate* is the...

> > *
> >     TimeStamp of next edit targeted for replication. Used for **calculating lag**,
> >     * as if this timestamp is greater than timestamp of last shipped, it means there's
> >     * at least one edit pending
> >     replication.

To make things more clear and obvious ;) the value of `replicationDelay` is [further](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/replication/regionserver/ReplicationLoad.java#L80) used as `replicationLag`.